# check expiry date for one month interval only

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

I have **expiry date** in my table.

Example : 
if the current date is ex:27-03-2011. I want to Generate chart if the expiry date is 27-02-2011.
I want to check and generate the chart for only one month of the expiry date , After one month of the expiry date i dont want to check

algorithm :

```
if(CurrentDate > ExpiryDate && CurrentDate < 1-month-from-expiry)
{
   GenerateChart();
}
else
{
   //Don't do anything 
}
```

how to do this in query

table1

field type

expdate date

Ex:2012-01-20

Comment: Which language are you using ? PHP ?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you want a list of records which have expired in the last month:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ExpiryDate < NOW() AND ExpiryDate > DATE_ADD(NOW() INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
```

Comment: Can you copypaste the exct query you tries this with, please?

Comment: Is this answer missing a comma in the `DATE_ADD` function parameters? `DATE_ADD(NOW() INTERVAL -1 MONTH)` => `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)`